# Visually change theme via query string?

Tags: themes, query-string

Ok, so I have an interesting situation here.

I'm looking to have an option to "visually" change a theme via a query string. Basically over-riding the need to update the database and just temporarily change the look of the site (think sort of like the preview button in the Themes section?)

Here's an example:
Let's say I have a demo site that has the same content but I want to give people the option to see what the site will look like under different themes.

Instead of creating multiple blogs (networked or not), I want to keep things maintainable for the content and dynamically change the theme without actually setting it in the database. That way, if I have multiple users viewing the same blog they instantly see the default and can change the theme without updating the site for everyone else.

Is this possible??? I've tried thinking of alternatives and this is the only way I can think of. Any suggestions or answers would be great :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of plugins for something like this, but there are a lot of nuances between them (who can swtich, how to switch, etc).

See [*theme preview* tag](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/theme-preview) in repository for starters.